sbt-assembly breaking library import in jar
I'm trying to convert from using MySQL Connector/J to MariaDB Connector/J 2.7.12 in a Scala 2.12 project. After thinking there was a bug in the MariaDB driver for a week, I've discovered that the real issue is that the merge logic for sbt-assembly is swapping out libraries that cause the MariaDB driver to throw an error when connecting to MySQL 8.
The error in question is:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=192.168.240.7)(port=3306)(type=master) : Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server. plugin type was = 'caching_sha2_password'
  at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)

I know it's not the driver because I've used the same driver, Scala, and Java in a small, test app. That worked fine once I got rid of the merge logic in that build.sbt file and manually excluded the duplicates. Unfortunately, the actual app uses a lpt more libraries.
Is there a way to ensure that sbt-assembly picks the classes from the MariaDB Connector/J jar first? If not, does anyone have a build.sbt file that includes that driver?
Tried:

Swapping out the library.
Tried different versions of MariaDB Connector/J.
Connected to MySQL 8 when I use the mysql_native_password auth plugin.
Connected to MySQL server 5.7, but repeatedly fail to connect to MySQL server 8 out of the box.

Expecting: seamless replacement of the MySQL driver with the MariaDB driver.
EDIT: Here's the sample app that works. To break it, remove the excludeDependencies section and replace it with the standard merge logic.
Maria.scala
package com.test

import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException
import org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

object Maria {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    var connection:Connection = null

    try {
      println("Start...")
      // DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver())
      Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
      println("Registered driver")
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mariadb://maria-mysql2-1:3306/test?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true", 
        "root", "password")
        
      println(s"Connection valid: ${connection.isValid(5)}")

      val statement = connection.createStatement()
      val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id, name FROM test")
      while ( resultSet.next() ) {
        val id = resultSet.getInt("id")
        val name = resultSet.getString("name")
        println(s"> ${id}. ${name}")
      }
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        println(e.printStackTrace)
      }
    } finally {
      println("Close...")
      connection.close()
      println(s"Connection valid: ${connection.isValid(5)}")
    }
  }
}

build.sbt
version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
organization := "com.test"
scalaVersion := "2.12.19"
name := "Maria"

Compile / mainClass := Some("com.test.Maria")
assembly / mainClass := Some("com.test.Maria")
assembly / assemblyJarName := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.3.0",
  "org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client" % "2.7.12"
)

excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api"),
  ExclusionRule("org.slf4j", "jcl-over-slf4j")
)


Sbt assembly pack all your dependencies you set in build.sbt. I don't understand why the library you set is not being used the jar produced. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Just oit of curiosity, why do you want to use mariadb connector to connect to mysql?

@GastónSchabas The library is being used, but I think there are some cryptographic libraries that are getting overwritten (overloaded, maybe) from other imported library jars, so when the MariaDB driver tries to send the password to MySQL it's being encoded incorrectly. I added the sample app that works.

@Shadow MySQL Connector/J uses a license that is incompatible with our product. MariaDB Connect/J is more agreeable. :shrug:

Yeah, but it is for a different product, not for mysql.

MariaDB maintains compatibility with MySQL.

You could use sbt dependency tree to inspect transient dependencies and which version is being picked, and try to exclude dependencies if you suspect that some of them can be causing some conflict

In the title of your question, you said you are using sbt-assembly, but in the tags you choose sbt-native-packager. The code seems to be using sbt-assembly. Have you tried to pack your app using sbt-native-packager?

What's the full error you got when you run that example? Does it say something that makes you feel there is an issue with the dependencies you are using?

@GastónSchabas The error I get is the one in the post, about caching_sha2_password. I'll try the dependency tree and see if that turns up anything. Thanks.

Discrepancies between mariadb and mysql now creep in on driver level as well as the two products have different connection options. Mariadb driver does not support all features of mysql 8.0, 8.4 and 9.0.

Mysql from version 8.0 uses caching_sha2_password for user authentication by default. You need to either upgrade your driver to one that supports this authentication methid or downgrade the authentication required for the user.

This turned out to be a case of the build.sbt file breaking the program. The real app (not my sample app) used sbt-assembly to create a jar. There was logic to remove duplicates with MergeStrategy that was removing the MariaDB service files within the META-INF directory. Without those, the driver didn't know where to find the classes to work with caching_sha2_password.
